# Ansible Container: docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such container: web_data")

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose, ansible-container

I'm trying to share a volume between multiple Docker containers using Ansible Container and am getting the following error:

> docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("No such
>   container: web_data")

My container.yml looks like:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web_data:
    from: centos:7
    roles:
      - data
    volumes:
      - /var/www/deployment
    command: [tail, -f, /dev/null]
  nginx:
    from: centos:7
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    roles:
      - nginx
    volumes_from:
      - web_data
    command: [supervisord]
```

The error occurs when the second container starts building. I had a look [online](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-container/issues/564) and apparently using the `--debug` switch should fix this, bit it's not.

Ansible versions are:

```
ansible (2.5.0)
ansible-container (0.9.2)
```

Docker versions are:

```
docker (2.5.1)
docker-compose (1.12.0)
docker-py (1.10.6)
docker-pycreds (0.2.1)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that `volumes_from` is ignored by ansible-container build.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/reference.html#volumes-from